# sql (mysql) optimize query oder schema, avoiding full table scan

Tags: mysql, optimization, full-table-scan

I have one table with data. The table has entries for orders, each order has some types (or state e.g ordered, ..., polished, packed, shipped).

Now, I want to do this query.

```
select * from orders as o 
  where not exists
  (SELECT * from orders as oo 
    where 
    o.order = oo.order and 
    oo.type="SHIPMENT")
```

type and shipment have a index, but it is only used after doing a full scan. So the query takes far to long. I want to present the data directly.

Comment: Try "explain select * from orders as o where not exists(SELECT * from orders as oo where o.order = oo.order and oo.type="SHIPMENT")" and paste its output. Also lets us know what are the indexes you have on those tables.

Comment: I get the feeling that each real order can have more than one entry in the `orders` table, which confuses me (and that `orders.order` is not a unique key). What exactly is it you a trying to do?

Comment: Yes oders.order has multiple entries because for every stage from ordering until shipment the status of the order is recorded in this table.Here is the explain result, sry for the crapy no linefeed display... 1  PRIMARY  o  ALL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  2562815  Using where
2  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  oo  ref  type,order order  4  db.o.order 30  Using where

Comment: Here the eplain result formatted a little, so you can read it:id  | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra 
1 | PRIMARY | o | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2562815  Using where
| 2  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | oo | ref | type,order | order | 4 | db.o.order | 30 | Using where

Comment: Problem continues here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068609/mysql-using-indexes-in-ram-why-are-the-disks-running

Comment: Problem continues here:

[klick please have a look][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068609/mysql-using-indexes-in-ram-why-are-the-disks-running

Answer (score 0):

Having an index on `orders.type` doesn't necessarily mean that this index will be used. In fact, the index is not used if it's not selective enough. Also, mysql works a little faster if you use `NOT IN` or `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` approach instead of `NOT EXISTS` :

```
// LEFT JOIN/IS NULL:
SELECT o.* 
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN orders oo ON (oo.order = o.order AND oo.type="SHIPMENT")
WHERE oo.id IS NULL
```

Comment: okay this seams to be the wrong schema/aproach. Any better ideas how to get this to run fast? Other database sturcture?

Comment: I think that `LEFT JOIN` approach I posted should work faster than your original query (`oo.id` is a primary key in `orders`). I don't think you can do too much if your table, for example, has 1M records and just 4 different values for `type` column. The index on `type` won't be used in that query. You can try using index hint to force index usage and check if it improves performance. You may also try partitioning table by `type`.

Comment: okay i am open to using a different table structure aswell for this task, but i having it all in one table should be the fastest?

Comment: I think so. You can easily test it : `CREATE TABLE test_orders SELECT * FROM orders WHERE type = 'SHIPMENT'; ALTER TABLE test_orders ADD PRIMARY KEY (your_primary_key_column)`. Then check performance for query `SELECT o.* FROM orders o LEFT JOIN test_orders oo ON (oo.order = o.order) WHERE oo.primary_key_column IS NULL`