# MySQL using indexes in RAM; why are the disks running?

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, indexing

I have indices of 800M and told MySQL to use 1500M of RAM. After starting MySQL it uses 1000M on Windows 7 x64.

I want to execute this query:

```
SELECT oo.* FROM table o 
LEFT JOIN table oo ON (oo.order = o.order  AND oo.type="SHIPPED") 
WHERE o.type="ORDERED" and oo.type IS NULL
```

This finds all items not yet shipped . The execution plan tells me this:

[image: photo]

My indices are:

- `type_order`: Multiple index with `type` and `order`
- `order_type` with `order` as first index value, followed by `type`

So MySQL should use the index `type_order` from RAM and then pick out the few entries with the `order_type` index. I'm expecting only about 1000 non shipped items, so this query should be really fast, but it isn't. Disks are going crazy....

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please add the `explain select` as text? The images is not very easy to read.

Comment: What are the number of rows in table o?

Comment: 25 Million rows. o and oo are the same table

Comment: This SQL does not seem to make much sense, but I may be wrong. Your requirement of oo.type being NULL while requesting all fields from the oo table seems contradictory.

Comment: How did you tell MySQL to use 1500M RAM? Which MySQL's sys parameters did you change?

Answer (score 0):

The query says `SELECT sometable.*`, so for 1000 matching rows, there will be 1000 fetches of all the fields from the table.  Whether the `WHERE` part indexes are fully loaded into ram or not would only help some.  The data fields still have to be retrieved.  Odds are, they are scattered all over the disk.  So, of course the disk(s) will be doing a thousand small reads.